# EsLint configuration for empty blocks on one line

Tags: eslint

I am trying to set esLint to format the empty blocks as a one liner.

For example, left is incorrect, right is desired behaviour.

As reference, left is incorrect, and right is correct.

[image]

I have tried to play with the following settings without success:

```
{
    "padded-blocks": ["error", { "blocks": "never" }],
    "padding-line-between-statements": [
      "error",
      {"blankLine": "never", "prev": "empty", "next": "*"},
      {"blankLine": "never", "prev": "*", "next": "empty"},
      {"blankLine": "never", "prev": "function", "next": "*"},
      {"blankLine": "never", "prev": "*", "next": "function"}
    ]
}
```

Would appreciate some input on the subject.
Thanks.

I have tried to set some configs on the "padded-blocks" and

```
{
    "padded-blocks": ["error", { "blocks": "never" }],
    "padding-line-between-statements": [
      "error",
      {"blankLine": "never", "prev": "empty", "next": "*"},
      {"blankLine": "never", "prev": "*", "next": "empty"},
      {"blankLine": "never", "prev": "function", "next": "*"},
      {"blankLine": "never", "prev": "*", "next": "function"}
    ]
}
```

Comment: This is a formatting issue, not a linting one. You should use something like Prettier for this.